# Android: Gap between Fragment and TextView in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am coding an application that is running on a **Nexus10**. I don't think that matters. I am using **Android version 4.4.2**.

I am experimenting with using a fragment to display a common group of `TextViews` that are displayed as the top 3 elements of an `Activity` that uses a `LinearLayout`.

I am not doing anything formatting outside of the following two `LinearLayout` XML snippets.

In the first (the parent level) I have a fragment and two text views. There is a **huge gap** that shows up between the fragment and the `TextViews`. If I remove the `android:layout_height="0dp"` and `android:layout_weight="1"` attributes from the fragment tag then the fragment doesn't get displayed at all. Does anyone see why I might be getting this **huge gap** between the fragment and the two TextViews displayed below it? Thanks!

Here is a the parent (`Activity`) level Layout. And below it is the `fragment` specific layout.

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    androidrientation="vertical" >
    <fragment
        android:name="com.srcinc.drphilos.ChemicalNameAndC asNumberFragment"
        android:id="@+id/chemical_name_and_cas_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
    /> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/healthEffectsSummaryLabel"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/toxletText" 
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    /> 
</LinearLayout>
```

And following is the fragment specific layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android=http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    androidrientation="vertical" >  
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chemicalName"
        android:textStyle="bold" 
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/casNumberText" 
        style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Large"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="5dp" 
        android:background="#DADADA" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the

```
android:layout_height="0dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"
```

you are telling the fragment to grow and fill all the empty space in screen.

If what you want is the TextViews to appear just after your fragment, the parameter you should put is wrap_content:

```
<fragment
    android:name="com.srcinc.drphilos.ChemicalNameAndC asNumberFragment"
    android:id="@+id/chemical_name_and_cas_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
/>
```

Comment: I could swear that I tried that early on, and even again! You are magic evaristokbza! It works now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
androidrientation="vertical" >
<fragment
    android:name="com.srcinc.drphilos.ChemicalNameAndC asNumberFragment"
    android:id="@+id/chemical_name_and_cas_number"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="8"
/> 
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/healthEffectsSummaryLabel"
    android:textStyle="bold" 
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/toxletText" 
    style="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="0dp" 
    android:layout_weight="1"
/>
```

This will divide your whole screen as 8parts fragment and 1:1 part TextViews. Let me know if this is not what you are looking for.